# Big tree identification

Tags: identification, trees

I have this tree in my garden and I am courious to know what kind of tree it is and how big will it grow?
Can anyone identify it?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like *Betula pendula* commonly known as Silver Birch. The white bark is typical of these trees - they do produce male and female catkins in early spring.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betula_pendula

Comment: Be warned that silver birch is very "insect-friendly". That might seem like a good thing, except that they attract plagues of aphids, which don't seem to harm to tree but can spread elsewhere. I leave my wheelie bins for weekly collection close to a silver birch tree, and sometimes the bin has thousands of aphids crawling all over it after being left there for a few hours!

Comment: Interesting. What is it about this tree that makes it attract so many aphids?

Comment: I can confirm the insect friendly condition.  They do make great candle holders once its lifespan has completed.  Royal Frost Birch is an alternative that resists the bore beetle.